# Find an onto Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find an onto homomorphism from the additive group $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers to the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}^*$. Justify and find its kernel.

Comment: there is no  multiplicative group of all complex numbers....

Comment: I think he meant ($\mathbb{C}$ \ {0} , *)

Comment: Hint: Maybe it is easier for you to solve this over $\mathbb R$ rather than $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @ Bhaskar Are u sure?? Since my professor asked me in the assignment...

Comment: Pranay, see Vader's comment to understand Bhaskar's.

Comment: Hint: find a function such that $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$.